# Can I re-use a Actionscript 3 NetConnection?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, amfphp

this is probably a noob question, but since I am new to Flash and AS3, here it goes...

Can I somehow re-use a AS3 NetConnection?

I am trying to create a AMFPHP class, that handles the connection, so I can re-use that initial connection whenever I want to make a call to a AMFPHP method.

Here is my code thus far,

```
package com.utils
{
    public class amfphp 
    {
        private var gateway:String = "http://localhost/amfphp/gateway.php";
        private var connection:NetConnection = new NetConnection;

        private function con(gate:String, con:NetConnection):void {
            //connect to the gateway file
            con.connect(gate);
            return con;
        }
    }
}
```

Thanx in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's right, your solution is workable. One little thing what I say because you said you are are new to as3. Your function can't return with the connection object, because the return value is set to void.

All the best.

Tamas

Comment: Aaah ok I see, so if I set it to `:NetConnection` instead of `:void`, it should work?